# Why Debian security updates are not installed when using "apt upgrade"? (it needs to be forced with "-t stable-security")

Tags: debian, apt, security

Debian security updates are not installed when using commands like `apt upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade`. I also tried with `apt-get` instead of `apt`.

However a command like `apt upgrade -t stable-security` or `apt install nodejs -t stable-security` will install security updates (for example https://www.debian.org/security/2022/dsa-5170).

Do you know why? This issue happens on my Debian stable laptop but I also have a Debian stable server (VPS) that does not have this issue. I checked that `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is the same on both installations and there is no `/etc/apt/preferences` file.

Here are the uncommented lines of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (based on https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stable main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stable-security main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stable-security main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main
```

To answer the question from the comments, here is the output of `apt policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=bullseye-backports,n=bullseye-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=bullseye-backports,n=bullseye-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=11-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bullseye-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bullseye-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 990 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main i386 Packages
     release v=11.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 990 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Note that previously I also had https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian displayed there but I commented it in `/etc/apt/sources.list` when searching the issue (it did not solve the problem when trying again `apt update` and `apt upgrade`).

We can see that the pinning priority of `stable` is higher than `stable-security`, which seems to be the issue, do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priority of 990 corresponds to the default release; in all likelihood, there’s a configuration entry saying

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

or equivalent.

If you remove that, everything should sort itself out.

Alternatively, as [mentioned in the Debian 11 release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#security-archive), you can keep an `APT::Default-Release" setting, as long as you change it to

```
APT::Default-Release "/^bullseye(|-security|-updates)$/";
```

For most scenarios where `Default-Release` is useful, I find pinning to be more appropriate.

Comment: My comment was removed but it would be useful to keep it for the additional information it contains and in case someone reading has an idea for the question: https://web.archive.org/web/20221014201920/https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720984/why-debian-security-updates-are-not-installed-when-using-apt-upgrade-it-need

Comment: Security updates are provided separately [so that there’s no delay because of mirror propagation](https://www.debian.org/security/faq#mirror) (some of the regular Debian mirrors are slow to update). Security updates are merged into the main repositories whenever a point release is made, so users who aren’t tracking the security repository end up getting them anyway.